# Error in retriving data from database

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to retrive my first name and last name for viewprofile.php but i'm getting resource ID#5 . I am CREATING session in Login page after successful authentication. And I am trying to use it here. I'm trying to use a session which has been created to fetch the data from the database.

```
<html>
<h1> My Profile</h1>
<?php
session_start();
require "config.php";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", $db_user, $db_pass);

if(!$con)
    {
die('cound not connect: '. mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

# include 'new.php'; 
echo $_SESSION['username'];
#$usname = $_SESSION['username'];
#echo 'local var: ',  $usname;
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE uname='".$_SESSION['username']."'" ;

#echo $sql1 ;
$result= mysql_query($sql1)or die(mysql_error());
#echo "res: " . $result;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
echo"</br>";
}

mysql_close($con); 

?>

</html>
```

I'm getting resource ID#5. Searched numerous places no luck. Kindly help

Comment: $result isn't a string that you can echo

Comment: I have commented that even then it won't display the desired result. Fixed the question!

Comment: Where you get wrong results?

Comment: I dont get any error. However, I don't get my result as well. It's blank. I am supposed to get firstname and lastname from the database (when retrived using sessions and queried from database). And yes they do exist in database.

I just get resource ID#5 rather than priting the echo statement

Comment: After the mysql_query put and echo mysql_num_rows($result);  Is this 0?

Comment: Thanks for helping out. It's 1

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken `mysql_fetch_array` will give you values that can be expressed as $row[0], $row[1] etc whereas `mysql_fetch_assoc` is what you're trying to use to get $row['fname'] etc

Change your code to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

In either case a `print_r($row)` within your while loop will you how it's made up.

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { however the default is MYSQL_BOTH so the current usage by OP would still work.

Comment: Tried both while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 and $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC same result.

My Profile

res: Resource id #5

Comment: oh. Monica, print_r($row) in the while loop and show us its output. $result will always show as Resource id

Comment: res: Resource id #5Array ( [fname] => [lname] => [uname] => [pass] => [email] => [gender] => 0 [phone] => )

Comment: @popnoodles if you are going to use MYSQL_ASSOC you can't use it with mysql_fetch_assoc() which doesn't accept a 2nd argument either way.

Comment: Sorry cryptic, I had pages for both functions open and forgot which was which

Comment: It's selecting a row. Does the SQL that you echo contain the username and is that working when you run it directly (not PHP)? The result you get suggests it's asking for where uname='' and that there is an empty row (except gender which = 0) to be selected.

Comment: thanks Guys! It worked! There was an incomplete row in the DB ..and may be that was the reason it was fetching some random results!